# Marshal and Unmarshal XML containing xmlns:wcm and xmlns:xsi correctly

Tags: xml, go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I'm trying to handle reading and writing of Windows Autounattend.xml files in order to create and modify them. I'm unable to get `xmlns:wcm` and `xmlns:xsi` attributes be marshaled and unmarshaled correctly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<unattend xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend">
    <settings pass="windowsPE">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SetupUILanguage>
                <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            </SetupUILanguage>
            <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <DiskConfiguration>
                <Disk wcm:action="add">
                    <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                    <WillWipeDisk>true</WillWipeDisk>
                    <CreatePartitions>
                        <!-- Windows RE Tools partition -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Size>300</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <!-- System partition (ESP) -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <Type>EFI</Type>
                            <Size>100</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <!-- Microsoft reserved partition (MSR) -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <Type>MSR</Type>
                            <Size>128</Size>
                        </CreatePartition>
                        <!-- Windows partition -->
                        <CreatePartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <Type>Primary</Type>
                            <Extend>true</Extend>
                        </CreatePartition>
                    </CreatePartitions>
                    <ModifyPartitions>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>1</Order>
                            <PartitionID>1</PartitionID>
                            <Label>WINRE</Label>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                            <TypeID>DE94BBA4-06D1-4D40-A16A-BFD50179D6AC</TypeID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>2</Order>
                            <PartitionID>2</PartitionID>
                            <Label>System</Label>
                            <Format>FAT32</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>3</Order>
                            <PartitionID>3</PartitionID>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                        <ModifyPartition wcm:action="add">
                            <Order>4</Order>
                            <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                            <Label>Windows</Label>
                            <Letter>C</Letter>
                            <Format>NTFS</Format>
                        </ModifyPartition>
                    </ModifyPartitions>
                </Disk>
            </DiskConfiguration>
            <ImageInstall>
                <OSImage>
                    <InstallTo>
                        <DiskID>0</DiskID>
                        <PartitionID>4</PartitionID>
                    </InstallTo>
                    <InstallToAvailablePartition>false</InstallToAvailablePartition>
                </OSImage>
            </ImageInstall>
            <UserData>
                <ProductKey>
                    <Key></Key>
                    <WillShowUI>Never</WillShowUI>
                </ProductKey>
                <AcceptEula>true</AcceptEula>
                <FullName>admin</FullName>
                <Organization></Organization>
            </UserData>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="offlineServicing">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-LUA-Settings" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <EnableLUA>false</EnableLUA>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="generalize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipRearm>1</SkipRearm>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="specialize">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <InputLocale>0409:00000409</InputLocale>
            <SystemLocale>en-US</SystemLocale>
            <UILanguage>en-US</UILanguage>
            <UILanguageFallback>en-US</UILanguageFallback>
            <UserLocale>en-US</UserLocale>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP-UX" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <SkipAutoActivation>true</SkipAutoActivation>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-SQMApi" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <CEIPEnabled>0</CEIPEnabled>
        </component>
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ComputerName>-PC</ComputerName>
            <ProductKey></ProductKey>
        </component>
    </settings>
    <settings pass="oobeSystem">
        <component name="Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS"
            xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoLogon>
                <Password>
                    <Value></Value>
                    <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                </Password>
                <Enabled>true</Enabled>
                <Username>admin</Username>
            </AutoLogon>
            <OOBE>
                <HideEULAPage>true</HideEULAPage>
                <HideOEMRegistrationScreen>true</HideOEMRegistrationScreen>
                <HideOnlineAccountScreens>true</HideOnlineAccountScreens>
                <HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>true</HideWirelessSetupInOOBE>
                <NetworkLocation>Home</NetworkLocation>
                <SkipUserOOBE>true</SkipUserOOBE>
                <SkipMachineOOBE>true</SkipMachineOOBE>
                <ProtectYourPC>1</ProtectYourPC>
            </OOBE>
            <UserAccounts>
                <LocalAccounts>
                    <LocalAccount wcm:action="add">
                        <Password>
                            <Value></Value>
                            <PlainText>true</PlainText>
                        </Password>
                        <Description></Description>
                        <DisplayName>admin</DisplayName>
                        <Group>Administrators</Group>
                        <Name>admin</Name>
                    </LocalAccount>
                </LocalAccounts>
            </UserAccounts>
            <RegisteredOrganization></RegisteredOrganization>
            <RegisteredOwner>admin</RegisteredOwner>
            <DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>false</DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet>
            <FirstLogonCommands>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Description>Control Panel View</Description>
                    <Order>1</Order>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel" /v StartupPage /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f</CommandLine>
                    <RequiresUserInput>true</RequiresUserInput>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>2</Order>
                    <Description>Control Panel Icon Size</Description>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ControlPanel" /v AllItemsIconView /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f</CommandLine>
                </SynchronousCommand>
                <SynchronousCommand wcm:action="add">
                    <Order>3</Order>
                    <RequiresUserInput>false</RequiresUserInput>
                    <CommandLine>cmd /C wmic useraccount where name="admin" set PasswordExpires=false</CommandLine>
                    <Description>Password Never Expires</Description>
                </SynchronousCommand>
            </FirstLogonCommands>
            <TimeZone>Central Standard Time</TimeZone>
        </component>
    </settings>
</unattend>
```

I tried to use `xml.Name`,`xml.Attr`, and string for this with no luck

```golang
const (
    // A generic XML header suitable for use with the output of Marshal.
    Header = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` + "\n"
    WCM    = `http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State`
    XSI    = `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`
)

type UserData struct {
    AcceptEula   bool   `xml:"AcceptEula"`
    FullName     string `xml:"FullName"`
    Organization string `xml:"Organization"`
    ProductKey   struct {
        Key        string `xml:"Key"`
        WillShowUI string `xml:"WillShowUI"`
    } `xml:"ProductKey"`
}

type OSImage struct {
    XMLName                     xml.Name `xml:"OSImage"`
    InstallToAvailablePartition bool     `xml:"InstallToAvailablePartition"`
    InstallToDiskID             uint32   `xml:"InstallTo>DiskID"`
    InstallToPatitionID         uint32   `xml:"InstallTo>ParitionID"`
}

type ImageInstall struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ImageInstall"`
    OSImage OSImage  `xml:"OSImage"`
}

type CreatePartition struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"CreatePartition"`
    Order   uint32   `xml:"Order"`
    Type    string   `xml:"Type"`
    Size    uint64   `xml:"Size,omitempty"`
    Extend  bool     `xml:"Extend,omitempty"`
    Action  xml.Attr `xml:"action,attr"`
}
type ModifyPartition struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"ModifyPartition"`
    Order       uint32   `xml:"Order"`
    PartitionID uint32   `xml:"PartitionID"`
    Label       string   `xml:"Label,omitempty"`
    Format      string   `xml:"Format,omitempty"`
    TypeID      string   `xml:"TypeID,omitempty"`
    Letter      string   `xml:"Letter,omitempty"`
    Action      xml.Attr `xml:"action,attr"`
}
type Disk struct {
    XMLName          xml.Name           `xml:"Disk"`
    Action           xml.Attr           `xml:"action,attr"`
    DiskID           uint32             `xml:"DiskID"`
    WillWipeDisk     bool               `xml:"WillWipeDisk"`
    CreatePartitions []*CreatePartition `xml:"CreatePartitions>."`
    ModifyPartitions []*ModifyPartition `xml:"ModifyPartitions>."`
}

type DiskConfiguration struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"DiskConfiguration"`
    Disks   []*Disk  `xml:"Disk"`
}

type SetupUILanguage struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name    `xml:"SetupUILanguage"`
    UILanguage *UILanguage `xml:"UILanguage"`
}

type UserLocale struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"UserLocale"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type InputLocale struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"InputLocale"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type SystemLocale struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"SystemLocale"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type UILanguage struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"UILanguage"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type UILanguageFallback struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"UILanguageFallback"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type EnableLUA struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"EnableLUA"`
    Value   bool     `xml:",chardata"`
}

type SkipRearm struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"SkipRearm"`
    Value   int32    `xml:",chardata"`
}

type SkipAutoActivation struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"SkipAutoActivation"`
    Value   bool     `xml:",chardata"`
}
type CEIPEnabled struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"CEIPEnabled"`
    Value   int32    `xml:",chardata"`
}
type ComputerName struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ComputerName"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}
type ProductKey struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"ProductKey"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Password struct {
    XMLName   xml.Name `xml:"Password"`
    Value     string   `xml:"Value"`
    PlainText bool     `xml:"PlainText"`
}

type AutoLogon struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name `xml:"AutoLogon"`
    Enabled  bool     `xml:"Enabled"`
    Username string   `xml:"Username"`
    Password Password `xml:"Password"`
}

type OOBE struct {
    XMLName                   xml.Name `xml:"OOBE"`
    HideEULAPage              bool     `xml:"HideEULAPage,omitempty"`
    HideOEMRegistrationScreen bool     `xml:"HideOEMRegistrationScreen,omitempty"`
    HideOnlineAccountScreens  bool     `xml:"HideOnlineAccountScreens,omitempty"`
    HideWirelessSetupInOOBE   bool     `xml:"HideWirelessSetupInOOBE,omitempty"`
    NetworkLocation           string   `xml:"NetworkLocation,omitempty"`
    SkipUserOOBE              bool     `xml:"SkipUserOOBE,omitempty"`
    SkipMachineOOBE           bool     `xml:"SkipMachineOOBE,omitempty"`
    ProtectYourPC             int32    `xml:"ProtectYourPC,omitempty"`
}

type LocalAccount struct {
    XMLName     xml.Name `xml:"LocalAccount"`
    Action      xml.Attr `xml:"action,attr"`
    Password    Password `xml:"Password"`
    Description string   `xml:"Description"`
    DisplayName string   `xml:"DisplayName"`
    Group       string   `xml:"Group"`
    Name        string   `xml:"Name"`
}

type LocalAccounts struct {
    XMLName      xml.Name
    LocalAccount []*LocalAccount `xml:"LocalAccount"`
}

type UserAccounts struct {
    XMLName       xml.Name      `xml:"UserAccounts"`
    LocalAccounts LocalAccounts `xml:"LocalAccounts"`
}

type RegisteredOrganization struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"RegisteredOrganization"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}
type RegisteredOwner struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"RegisteredOwner"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}
type DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet"`
    Value   bool     `xml:",chardata"`
}

type CommandLine struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"CommandLine"`
    Value   string   `xml:",innerxml"`
}

type SynchronousCommand struct {
    XMLName           xml.Name    `xml:"SynchronousCommand"`
    Order             uint32      `xml:"Order"`
    Description       string      `xml:"Description"`
    RequiresUserInput bool        `xml:"RequiresUserInput"`
    CommandLine       CommandLine `xml:"CommandLine"`
}

type FirstLogonCommands struct {
    XMLName            xml.Name              `xml:"FirstLogonCommands"`
    SynchronousCommand []*SynchronousCommand `xml:"SynchronousCommand"`
}
type TimeZone struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"TimeZone"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
}

type Component struct {
    XMLName               xml.Name `xml:"component"`
    Name                  string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    ProcessorArchitecture string   `xml:"processorArchitecture,attr"`
    PublicKeyToken        string   `xml:"publicKeyToken,attr"`
    Language              string   `xml:"language,attr"`
    VersionScope          string   `xml:"versionScope,attr"`
    // optional compontents
    SetupUILanguage            *SetupUILanguage            `xml:"SetupUILanguage"`
    UserLocale                 *UserLocale                 `xml:"UserLocale"`
    InputLocale                *InputLocale                `xml:"InputLocale"`
    SystemLocale               *SystemLocale               `xml:"SystemLocale"`
    UILanguage                 *UILanguage                 `xml:"UILanguage"`
    UILanguageFallback         *UILanguageFallback         `xml:"UILanguageFallback"`
    DiskConfiguration          *DiskConfiguration          `xml:"DiskConfiguration,omitempty"`
    ImageInstall               *ImageInstall               `xml:"ImageInstall,omitempty"`
    UserData                   *UserData                   `xml:"UserData,omitempty"`
    EnableLUA                  *EnableLUA                  `xml:"EnableLUA,omitempty"`
    SkipRearm                  *SkipRearm                  `xml:"SkipRearm,omitempty"`
    ProductKey                 *ProductKey                 `xml:"ProductKey,omitempty"`
    ComputerName               *ComputerName               `xml:"ComputerName,omitempty"`
    SkipAutoActivation         *SkipAutoActivation         `xml:"SkipAutoActivation,omitempty"`
    CEIPEnabled                *CEIPEnabled                `xml:"CEIPEnabled,omitempty"`
    AutoLogon                  *AutoLogon                  `xml:"AutoLogon,omitempty"`
    OOBE                       *OOBE                       `xml:"OOBE,omitempty"`
    UserAccounts               *UserAccounts               `xml:"UserAccounts"`
    RegisteredOrganization     *RegisteredOrganization     `xml:"RegisteredOrganization,omitempty"`
    RegisteredOwner            *RegisteredOwner            `xml:"RegisteredOwner,omitempty"`
    DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet *DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet `xml:"DisableAutoDaylightTimeSet,omitempty"`
    FirstLogonCommands         *FirstLogonCommands         `xml:"FirstLogonCommands,omitempty"`
    TimeZone                   *TimeZone                   `xml:"TimeZone,omitempty"`
}

type Settings struct {
    XMLName    xml.Name     `xml:"settings"`
    Pass       string       `xml:"pass,attr"`
    Components []*Component `xml:"component"`
}

type Unattend struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name    `xml:"unattend"`
    XMLNS    xml.Attr    `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
    Settings []*Settings `xml:"settings"`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlns:wcm` and `xmlns:xsi` are not the real attributes, and they are processed in a special way. Your XML has neither elements nor attributes from `wcm` and `xsi` schemas, and they are dropped. Why do you need them in your code?

Still If you really-really need them, you can add the following field to the `Component` structure:

```
    Attr                  []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
```

[`xml.Unmarshal` documentation says](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml#Unmarshal:%7E:text=associated%20tag%20containing-,%22%2Cany%2Cattr%22,-%2C%20Unmarshal%20records%20the):

> If the XML element has an attribute not handled by the previous rule and the struct has a field with an associated tag containing ",any,attr", Unmarshal records the attribute value in the first such field.

Here is an example: https://go.dev/play/p/tGDh5Ay1kZW

```
func main() {
    var u Unattend
    err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(document), &u)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for _, a := range u.Settings[0].Components[0].Attr {
        fmt.Printf("Unmatched attributes: %s:%s = %s\n", a.Name.Space, a.Name.Local, a.Value)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Unmatched attributes: xmlns:wcm = http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State
Unmatched attributes: xmlns:xsi = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
```

Note 1. What is not so good with this *solution*: it handles extra attributes in `<component/>` only. But `xmlns:XXX` attributes can appeare in any element. In general case you should add `Attr` array in all structures of your data model.

Note 2. The attributes `xmlns:wcm` and `xmlns:xsi` bear no business logic. They give no information regarding settings and components. Do you really need them?

Note 3. There is absolutely no requirement to name these attributes `xmlns:wcm` and `xmlns:xsi`. It is just a common practice. XML document can name them `xmlns:foo` and `xmlns:bar` - it is perfectly valid. Even the values `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State"` and `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` have no meaning. They could be any string, the only requirement is to match [URI format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt). E.g. `urn:microsoft:wmi-config:2002:state` is as valid as `http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State`

Parsing those attributes in `Component` is very specific and could fail on olther valid XML documents that declare those attributes in other elements or with other suffixes or values.

**UPDATE**

Marshalling works not as expected. `xml.Marshal` handles `xmlns` namespace specifically and converts `Attr` for `xmlns:wcm` and `xmlns:xsi` into the namespace `_xmlns`

```xml
<component name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-SPP" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:_xmlns="xmlns" _xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" _xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
...
</component>
```

The workaround is to use a special type for the attributes:

```
type XMLNSAttr struct {
    Name  xml.Name
    Value string
}

func (a XMLNSAttr) Label() string {
    if a.Name.Space == "" {
        return a.Name.Local
    }
    if a.Name.Local == "" {
        return a.Name.Space
    }
    return a.Name.Space + ":" + a.Name.Local
}

func (a *XMLNSAttr) UnmarshalXMLAttr(attr xml.Attr) error {
    a.Name = attr.Name
    a.Value = attr.Value
    return nil
}

func (a XMLNSAttr) MarshalXMLAttr(name xml.Name) (xml.Attr, error) {
    return xml.Attr{
        Name: xml.Name{
            Space: "",
            Local: a.Label(),
        },
        Value: a.Value,
    }, nil
}
```

This type does the trick by constructing an attribute with the namespace embedded into the local name. The field

```golang
    Attr                  []xml.Attr `xml:",any,attr"`
```

correctly decodes/encodes `xmlns:xxx` attributes

Example: https://go.dev/play/p/VDofREl5nf1

Output:

```
Unmatched attributes: xmlns:wcm = http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State
Unmatched attributes: xmlns:xsi = http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
<unattend>
  <settings pass="windowsPE">
    <component name="Microsoft-Windows-International-Core-WinPE" processorArchitecture="amd64" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" language="neutral" versionScope="nonSxS" xmlns:wcm="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WMIConfig/2002/State" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        ...
    </component>
    ...
  </settings>
</unattend>
```

Comment: That workaround solved it, thanks. Also the reason I needed wcm and xsi is because without them Windows does not accept the xml file